# 403 forbidden expressjs backend

Tags: node.js, express

```
GET http://localhost:5000/booksIdea/show 403 (Forbidden)
```

i check the token in the website https://jwt.io/ i got invalid signature so i guess why the problem came from but i ignore how to fix it
i searched abt this error and this is what i found : Receiving a 403 response is the server telling you, “I’m sorry. I know who you are–I believe who you say you are–but you just don’t have permission to access this resource. Maybe if you ask the system administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please don’t bother me again until your predicament changes.”

API GET function on front end:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const ShowBooks = () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("usertoken")

    return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/booksIdea/show", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, //here remove + in template litereal
        },
      })
      .then(res => {
          console.log("Success")
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })

}
```

backend app.js

```
const express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = 5000
const routes = require("./routes");
const con = require('./db')
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
// database connect 

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
  });

  //cookie 
  app.use(cookieParser())
//routes
// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/", routes);


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

here is routes

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var Controller = require('./controller')
var authController = require('./authController')
var BooksIdeaController = require('./BooksIdeaController')
router.post('/register',Controller.register);
router.post('/login',authController.login);
router.post('/booksIdea/:id',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.addComment)
router.post('/booksIdea/addbook',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.addBookIdea)
router.get('/booksIdea/show',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.showBookIdea)
router.put('/booksIdea/edit/:id',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.UpdateBookIdea)
router.delete('/booksIdea/delete/:id',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.DeleteBookIdea)
module.exports = router;
```

> authController

```
const con = require('./db');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const app = express()
module.exports.login=function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.name;
    var password=req.body.password;
    con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
          res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query'
            })
      }else{
        if(results.length >0){
          bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function (err, result) {
            if (result == true) {
        jwt.sign({user:results},'configSecret',(err,token)=>{
          res.json({
            token:token
          })


        });



            //   res.json({
            //     status:true,
            //     message:'successfully authenticated'
            // })
            } else {
              res.json({
                      status:false,
                      message:"username and password does not match"
                     });
            }
          });
        }
        else{
          res.json({
              status:false,    
            message:"username does not exits"
          });
        }
      }
    });
}

module.exports.home=function(req,res){
res.send('hello');
}
//////
// if(password==results[0].password){

  // }else{
  //    
  // }
  module.exports.verify = function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    // Get auth header value
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    // Check if bearer is undefined
    if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
      // Split at the space
      const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
      // Get token from array
      const bearerToken = bearer[1];
      // Set the token
      req.token = bearerToken;
      // Next middleware
      next();
    } else {
      // Forbidden
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }

  }
```

How can I fix this error? thank you in advance for your help

Comment: please post your routes

Comment: Do other routes ( such as `/booksIdea/:id'` or `/booksIdea/addbook` ) work or return the same error?

Comment: with postman it worked but in react i got this issue

Comment: I added an answer, let me know

Comment: Can you add code for authController.verify?

Answer (score 0):

Check your localstorage `localStorage.getItem("usertoken")`

Your token can be:

1. missing or undefined
2. incorrect token - probably a typo

Comment: so i comment out app.use(cors()) , i got this Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/booksIdea/show' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've updated my answer. It's definitely not a cors() issue then. Any luck tracing the token and making sure it's not blank/undefined?

Comment: Add quotes: replace `Authorization` with `'Authorization'`

Comment: still the problem exists :/